# How to create a php string strip function

Tags: php, string, split

I am attempting to create a function of which manipulates postcodes, but as postcodes in the UK are all different sizes im struggling to work it out, im attempting to pass (for example "DN11AA") this would then need to return the following, "dn|dn1-1|dn1-1aa"

Another example would be passing "B32B" - this would then return "b|b3-2|b3-2b"

Thank you for taking the time to read this :)

Comment: What is the logic for that particular splitting?

Comment: @deceze Hi, I am creating an online location app of which you search by postcode and brings back information.

Comment: it should be noted that uk postcodes are not typically written with hyphens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work.

```
function post($post){
 for($i = 0; $i < strlen($post); $i++)
    if(is_numeric(substr($post, $i, 1))){
       $j=$i;
       if(is_numeric(substr( $post, $i+2, 1)))$j++;          
       return substr($post, 0, $i).'|'.substr($post, 0, $j+1).'-'.substr($post, $j+1,1).'|'.substr($post, 0, $j+1).'-'.substr($post, $j+1);
    }

 }
```

edited, tested, works

Comment: thank you for your help, its almost perfect, at the moment it outputs, "dn|dn1-5|dn1-58aa" - it needs to output "dn|dn15-8|dn15-8aa".

Comment: If i send the following values through the function, dn151bc, b144aa, b11jl, l691dt

Outputs: dn|dn1-5|dn1-51bc, b|b1-4|b1-44aa, b|b1-1|b1-1jl, l|l6-9|l6-91dt

It needs to output, dn|dn15-1|dn15-1bc, b|b14-4|b14-4aa, b|b1-1|b1-1jl, l|l69-1|l69-1dt

Hope that makes sense :)

Answer (score 3):

There are standard regex codes for handling UK postcodes.

A fully comprehensive expression looks like this:

```
(GIR 0AA)|(((A[BL]|B[ABDFHLNRSTX]?|C[ABFHMORTVW]|D[ADEGHLNTY]|E[HNX]?|F[KY]|G[LUY]?|H[ADGPRSUX]|I[GMPV]|JE|K[ATWY]|L[ADELNSU]?|M[EKL]?|N[EGNPRW]?|O[LX]|P[AEHLOR]|R[GHM]|S[AEGKLMNOPRSTY]?|T[ADFNQRSW]|UB|W[ADFNRSV]|YO|ZE)[1-9]?[0-9]|((E|N|NW|SE|SW|W)1|EC[1-4]|WC[12])[A-HJKMNPR-Y]|(SW|W)([2-9]|[1-9][0-9])|EC[1-9][0-9]) [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})
```

You can use this in PHP as follows (for brevity I'll assume you've put the above code into a variable called `$postcode_regex`):

```
$pc_is_valid = preg_match($postcode_regex, $input_string);
```

Depending on exactly what you want to do with it, you may need to use other `preg_xxx()` functions, and maybe modify the above string, but it's hard to give clearer advice without more info.

See the Wikipedia article for more on how to parse postcodes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom